# java jars class

Tags: java, jar

I have developed one project(java), In that i have copied few jar files and has put all the jars in the classpath, Program is running fine. So I am packing th whole jar in one file and running it on Solaris system through a script file, In that script file i have mentionesd the command--"java -cp .:myproject.jar :lib/allexternaljars... mainclass" .

Problem- Since in script file i mentioned my all jar file names and hence it got populated with lot of characters and i have memory constraints particullar to the contents in the script file.

Is there any way that I can include all the jars in my project only or can i put all the classes of external jars in the project only as a package. I am using Eclipse IDE.

Will it work, Please assist.

@rs

Comment: Could you please clarify on *memory contraints*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using a different shell...the default shell in solaris (sh) has a limitation of 267 chars...

if you want to use eclipse to build to jar, set eclipse to export the dependencies as well this will create a folder inside the generated jar containing all the libs. (these libs will be automatically added to your class path .

Answer (score 0):

The default heap size for a Java virtual machine is 64 MByte. So if the application throws some sort of `OutOfMemoryError`, simply increase it:

```
java -Xmx128m -cp .:myproject.jar:lib/allexternaljars... mainclass
```

This would assign 128MByte.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

```
1.In the "Project Explorer", right click on your project folder.
2.Go to the "Build Path" and then select "Configure Build Path"
3.Then click the button "Add External JARs"
4.Now select the jar file from your computer.
```

and you are done.